# How to create subgroups for @mentions in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, mention

Right now I have a small group of people beta testing MS Teams in hopes that it would be a good team collaboration/communication tool.

But, I need one important feature to really make it most useful and I can't find it.

I know you can mention everybody with an @team or @channel, or a single user with @username. But can I create subgroup names that include a subset of the entire team?

Let's say I have a big team of 25 users. I want to create certain subgroups, like @group1 that only includes 10 of those users or @group2 that only has 5 of those user.

I need to have a one mention way to contact this subgroup without having to individually  mention each person or using @channel to mention to a lot of people who aren't interested.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: that's not a programming question, btw

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 channels:

- @group1
- @group2

Ask people to join a channel or add them manually.

Now you can mention them by that channel name i.e. @group1 or @group2

For example, imagine you have developer and operations teams in your "Adme Inc" company.

- You create a Team "AdmeInc".
- `General` channel is created automatically.
- You create a channel `Dev` in that team and add all developers to it
- You create a channel `Ops` in that team and add everyone in operations team to it.

Now everyone can chat in `General` about all kind of stuff.
Anyone can mention `@Dev` anywhere and everyone in developers team is notified.
Or they can mention `@Ops` anywhere and everyone in operations team is notified.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you could do that, but that is not quite a working solution for me. 
Everybody will be subscribed to all channels. They 'may' need to go into those at some point. But I need them to be able to tag subteam only. Plus, I need them to be able to tag the group from any channel's messages.

Comment: Good idea. It would be possible to create a bot that allowed users to create groups and then the bot would expand the groups.

Comment: @kingtermite yes, that's how Teams work - you can @-mention any channel in messages in any other channel and people on mentioned channel will be notified. I don't see why everyone needs to be subscribed to ALL channels.

Comment: @kingtermite added an example to my answer

Comment: Does this work this way anymore?  I can't seem to find anyway to add anyone to a channel, and when I mention a channel `@channel` it automatically notifies everyone in the team.

Comment: It's important to note that mentioning channels only works within teams (unfortunately). So you can't mention any channel in messages in any other channel, only in any other channel of the same team.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, MS Teams offers tags to achieve this. Tag the team members using your own defined tags. Then simply @-mention the tag name in a standard channel (or in a chat).
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-tags-in-teams-667bd56f-32b8-4118-9a0b-56807c96d91e

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).